# Unable to access graph after re-login

Tags: agens-graph

I created graph on AgensGraph.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# create graph g;
CREATE GRAPH
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# \q
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
agens=# \q
```

But, unable to access graph after re-login.

How to access graph after re-login

Answer (score 0):

Use "ALTER USER ... SET GRAPH_PATH TO ..." statement for set default graph on login.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# create graph g;
CREATE GRAPH
agens=# alter user agens set graph_path to g;
ALTER ROLE
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# \quit
```

After changing "GRAPH_PATH", You can access to your graph.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 v[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)
```